# ¿Cuál es la correcta sintaxis de arrow functions anidadas o múltiples funciones?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

Estoy intentando transcribir un seudo código a React, resulta que son varias pueden ser funciones o arrow funcions, como yo lo estoy desarrollando, cada una adentro de otra, pero sin embargo siempre me marca error de sintaxis, casi siempre después de cada función, ya probé colocando comas, punto y coma y es indiferente marca error. Este es un ejemplo de mi el código.

```
import React from 'react'
import * as THREE from 'three'                                                  

export default function MuchoTexto(){
          const MSDFShader = require('three-bmfont-text/shaders/msdf')

          function init(geometry, texture){
                  const material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial(MSDFShader({
                          map: texture,
                          color: 0xFFFFFF,
                          side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                          transparent: true,
                          negate: false,
                  }));
                  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
                  mesh.position.set(-80, 0, 0)

          }

          let createGeometry = require('three-bmfont-text')
          let loadFont = require('load-bmfont')
          const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()

          loadFont('fonts/Lato.fnt', (err, font) => {
                  let geometry = function createGeometry(
                          {
                                  font:font
                          })
                  geometry.update('Texto a Renderear')
                  //const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                  loader.load('fonts/Lato.png', (texture) => {
                          init(geometry, texture);
                          animate() //Aqui tambien marca error no se como llamar animate                       
                  })
          });
  }
```

Comment: Hola @Jorge Carretero, bienvenido al foro. Según ve en tu código no tienes declarada o no la pasas por parámetro la función `animate()` por eso te da error, por que no la encuentra. Una pregunta, porque importas modulos dentro de la función en vez de hacerlo como lo haces con `React` y `THREE`?

Comment: Veo cosas rarísimas en ese código. Además de lo ya comentado por @planta4, ¿por qué declaras `let createGeometry = require('three-bmfont-text')` y luego declaras la función `function createGeometry({font:font})`? ¿`animate()` es una función de `ThreeJs`?

Comment: La verdad lo desconozco @planta4 , asi viene el codigo de ejemplo en la pagina de npm de three-bmfont-text y de load-bmfont, a mi tambien me parece raro el código.

Comment: @JorgeCarretero, podrías explicar al detalle lo que quieres hacer para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Claro, explicaré según lo que leí three-bmfont-text nos permite escribir mucho texto en un ambiente 3D y eso es todo lo que quisiera lograr, en éste ejemplo rendearia "Texto a renderear", saludos